# How to get the content of an external page as a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

So I know there are many ways to get the content of an external page as a string (for example with PHP) but is there a way to get it as a javascript/JSON object (a DOM Window object for example) so I can easily manipulate it? I was thinking perhaps working with iframes, but as always, the same origin policy applies. I feel that this may not be possible by design, but I am interested to try. Does anyone have a creative solution for this? I don't want to use flash or sliverlight (because of iPhone issues).

Comment: Please explain your primary task, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Max, I am trying to extract the content of a div with a specific class from an external page (like www.google.com or www.ball.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** way to do it is through your server. Expose some AJAX method for the purpose of fetching external webpages (or one specific webpage) and let the server do the job instead of the client.

**Added:**

For PHP, you can do it this way:

1. Create file `getremotecontent.php`
2. Using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) fetch the URL you desire (in PHP file):

   ```
   $pagestr = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
   ```
3. Using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encode the resulting string into JSON object.

   ```
   $pagejson = json_encode($pagestr);
   ```
4. Next, send the appropriate headers:

   ```
   header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   ```
5. Finally, send the content of the encoded string:

   ```
   print $pagejson;
   ```
6. In Javascript, make a Ajax (XHR) request to `getremotecontent.php`. Server will get you your webpage, encode it into JSON format and give it back for you to process on the client side.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, could you provide a short code outline?

Comment: On your server-side code, whatever it is (Java/PHP/C#/etc.) you need to expose an AJAX method. Then from your Javascript you will be able to invoke an AJAX call to the exposed method. The method itself would then download the required web-page, however, that would happen on your server, therefore domain restriction policy won't apply.

Comment: I don't understand how to "expose" a method.

Comment: @Ben7005 What is your server language?

Comment: Really sorry for the long wait, I use PHP.

Comment: @Ben7005 Added info about PHP implementation.

Answer (score 1):

No. For security reasons, you can only access pages from the same domain as the one which runs your JavaScript. This is called [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: As there are ways to get the page as a string, why is there no way to get it as an object? Also, is there something that would parse the string into an object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get the page as a string - that would be a loophole in the SOP. But if you can, create a `<div id="page">` and then `$(#page).html(string);` - it won't render correctly but you should be able to examine the DOM. If that doesn't work, try to strip the header and all `script` elements.

Comment: That's a good idea. I know how to get the page as a string with PHP, so I'll try it.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: ... but only for pages in the same domain.